# HTML5 Canvas Brush

Tags: html, canvas

I have searched the web and found no answer. I want to draw lines on an HTML5's canvas element but having a texture that is not solid, rather custom. Just like brushes in Photoshop if you know them. For example, to have a line that looks like it was drawn with chalk or artist paint brush. Do you know a way to do it?

Comment: Please have a look at my code project article. may be useful to you. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/427422/Paint-Brush-Application-Using-HTML5-Canvas thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using libraries such as [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) or [Fabric.js](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js)?

You can also take a look at this blog entry that might be interesting for you:

http://rhyolight.posterous.com/new-brushes-for-harmony-canvas-app

If you want to develop everything from scratch you should put a lot of effort into it!

Answer (score 12):

### Why don't you use [croquis.js](https://github.com/disjukr/croquis.js)?

It has neat [brush implementation like photoshop](http://crosspop.github.io/Croquispop/brush-preview.html) :)

And here is [Demo](http://labs.crosspop.in/Croquispop/croquispop.html) which is using croquis.js.

[image: brush-preview]